# jQuery - Hide form on Submit

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate, submit, hide

I would like to hide my form on successful submission:

Here is a link to the testspace: http://www.bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_3.php

Its a combination PHP jQuery mongrel. At the moment I'm using jQuery validator and I have added custom script to change the class on the input fields wrapping div - as a way to show required fields.

Here is what I have in the PHP

```
<?php
```

$subject = "Website Contact Form Enquiry";

//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
//Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
}

//Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
    $hasError = true;
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}

//Check to make sure comments were entered
if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
        $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
    } else {
        $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
    }
}

//If there is no error, send the email
if(!isset($hasError)) {
    $emailTo = 'info@bgv.co.za'; //Put your own email address here
    $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nComments:\n $comments";
    $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

    mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    $emailSent = true;

}
```

}
?>

and here is the script area:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#contactform').validate({
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

            //restore the normal look
            $('#contactform div._required').removeClass('_required').addClass('xrequired');

            //stop if everything is ok
            if (errorList.length == 0) return;

            //Iterate over the errors
            for(var i = 0;i < errorList.length; i++)
                $(errorList[i].element).parent().removeClass('xrequired').addClass('_required');
        }
```

});
});

So at the moment when someone submits a valid form you see a new heading just under Contact form - its from here:

```
        <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
    <h1 class="success_form">Thank You!</h1>
    <?php } ?>
```

and below it is the data entered into the form.

But its the form shoing below that I want to hide.... Please help :)

Here is the new bit I added thanks to Flashbackzoo

```
        $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append(
    "<p>If you want to be kept in the loop...</p>" +
    "<p>Or you can contact...</p>"
    );
    $('h1.success_').removeClass('success_').addClass('success_form');
    $('#contactform').hide();

},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a submit handler...

```
$('#contactform').validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // your code...
    },
    submitHandler: function() {
        $('#contactform').hide();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your comment Brett. You could change your submitHandler to something like...

```
submitHandler: function() {
    $("#content").empty();
    $("#content").append(
        "<p>If you want to be kept in the loop...</p>" +
        "<p>Or you can contact...</p>"
    );
}
```

This will remove all child elements from #content using the .empty() method. Then add elements to #content using the .append() method. You can swap out #content for any selector you like.

Comment: One thing tho, when it does this... hide the form it also hides the form results

Comment: So you no longer see the thank you page. Like if you go through the process here> http://bgv.co.za/testspace/contact_2.php

Comment: I updated my answer, hope that helps. The jQuery documentation http://docs.jquery.com/ has good info on the methods mentioned

Comment: I have a question, in  your update you can output <p></p> data - which is great but I would need to output some php echo variables of what was input in the form - so if someone went through the form process and submitted valid data they would see a thank you page with their form input data reflected back. Do you know a way?