# jQuery hide form on submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form setup where a user can register, and on submittal, a PHP script runs which validates the user, and once that is done, it echoes a messagebox which jQuery quickly hides and then fades in over the course of 1 second. What I now want to do is to be able to hide that form on submittal, and I thought this might do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.mainsuccess,div.mainerror').hide(0).fadeIn(1000);
    $('form.register').submit(function() {
        $(this).hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Where `div.mainsuccess` is the success message, and `form.register` is the form (with a class of register). Now the first line works, which tells me the script is being called, but the form is not being hidden at all. I'm doing something stupid here, but I cannot figure out what?

I've tried to look through the jQuery API documentation for `submit()`, but I cannot understand what is being said. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if `.hide(0)` works correctly. Why don't you just use `.hide()` to hide immediately?

Comment: it does work correctly, my question is why don't the second and third lines work? (the part involving the form)

Comment: Does your webpage refresh after submitting the form? If so, the form doesn't hide because the page refreshes the DOM.

Comment: @Indranil actually, yes, that makes perfect sense. How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Added an answer, check if that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Hide form on Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801172/jquery-hide-form-on-submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason it may not work is because the form is submitting it's data and waiting for page to refresh... which means, it will stop all of it's javascript stuff coz it's pointless ... I could be wrong but hey, your hide would take 1 second to hide but your page could reload quicker.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.mainsuccess,div.mainerror').hide(0).fadeIn(1000);
    $('form.register').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();// will stop the form being submited...
        $(this).hide(1000);
        // do ajax here...
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Updated**

here is a list of tutorials

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/

http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

Videos ....
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CMTQtnZ0G0

Comment: Right, the return false is the key.

Comment: Sounds great and I understand the premise, but I wouldn't know AJAX if it hit me in the face!

Comment: think of ajax as an invisible iframe or window, you can send $_POST [in php or other serverside ] information then it will return source code back anything you wish on that page, using firebug, or developer tools such as chrome will allow you to see whats returned, if you wish to know more I can set up a chat room on stackoverflow and guide you that way

Comment: Would you be able to link me to an AJAX tutorial similar to what I want to accomplish here - and I am concerned about how AJAX would interact with the PHP I've already coded - which on submittal (a reload of a page), registers a user.

Comment: @Antilogical13 here are some links updated and a video this guy sounds alright :) it's for begginers hope it helps mate

Comment: @Val cheers, and thanks for the links. I've accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: I also thinks thats the way to go.

Comment: damn you, you stole my thunder hahaha :)

Comment: btw its `e.preventDefault()` as a callable function not as a property

Comment: @Val, just tried it with the parentheses at the end, and all it did was hide my form without a submittal, which I suppose is the intention of that script, but doesn't work for what I need.

Comment: @Antilogical13: You may want to use Indranill's method then. His hides it but still submits the form.

Comment: as my answer shows, or @Indranil answer is best you need an ajax to, post the stuff, to the server and whatever it returns back can be put somewhere on the page :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to incorporate an ajax call (I'm taking post) to call the php instead of reloading the page

```
$('form.register').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.post(url,$(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        alert('success');
        // data will return source code of the URL so you can grab that data and put it somewhere on the script like so.
        $('#result').html($(data).find('form'));//form can be replaced with anything
        // #result is the id of an element you wish to return the info to 
    });
    $(this).hide(1000);
});
```

And you'd be done.

[More info here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: I like your answer, maybe you should extend it by helping out how to use the returning data variable I will update this for you

Comment: True. But I guess it mostly depends on what the OP wants to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, seems that the form refreshes after submission, so it is still there.

I suggest using something like jQuery form: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Read up on it and you will find how to use it, and when it is submitted, it won't refresh, and using `hide()` you will be able to hide it.

N.B you will need jQuery referenced in your code to use jQuery form.

Enjoy.